# Is there something I am missing to configure the ads?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I have created a free application on Google Play Store that got uploaded, and I also have ads in it. They are interstitial ads. Before uploading the application, I tried the test interstitial ads and they worked just fine. But the game does not show any ad at all now that it is uploaded.

I did change all the necessary code for it to work.

For example, the adUnitId I changed it from the test one to the real one, and also put the request as a non-test request. I also have configured the ad settings enabling google admob and also copied the admob app id for android.

I created a mediation group, even though the only source is admob. And I also linked the app to the admob.

I have already received email from admob and also google, both approving everything (app approved, payment method approved and so on).

I can't find any tutorial so I am not sure if I am missing something. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to wait an hour or so after all the configuration.